# Can a user receive the Suffrage badge more than once?

Tags: support, badges

Fairly self-explanatory, I think.  I had the [Suffrage](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/57/suffrage?userid=3522) badge from long ago and yesterday I used all 30 of my daily votes, but I don't see a x2 next to the badge on my user page.

Just curious.

Comment: Using up 30 votes is a very easy way to get a badge, which is great for encouraging new users to vote; but if you're allowed to receive it multiple times it devalues the badge system. Hence it's a one time badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

From: [Mark which badges are capable of being won > 1 time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/mark-which-badges-are-capable-of-being-won-1-time/39189#39189)

Badges that can be awarded more than once will say so in the description on the badge page, for example:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/33/favorite-question

> {blah blah blah badge description}. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  I've used all my votes a few times and never got the badge again.  This makes sense to me though.  If I were creating the badge system, this badge would serve to encourage people to get into the habit of voting.  The **Nice Answer** badge, however, would serve to recognize people for their good answers, and it makes sense to recognize all of them instead of only the first one.